# Sending Email in Java getting error couldn't connect to host

Tags: java, email

Original Post ~
I am trying to send an email through java but I am getting an error that says it couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 547; timeout -1;

I am trying to send it through gmail and I have imported two jar files, which are java mail api download – https://javaee.github.io/javamail/ java activation jar download – https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1

It takes forever to run and once it finally does finish it show that error.I would appreciate any help, even if it is just pointing me to a YouTube video or another post on this website. Thank you in advance.

Updated Post~
I had a comment saying to use 587 instead of 547 so I changed it but I am now getting an javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Username and password not accepted error. I have googled and even looked on stack overflow and they say to change a setting in my google account but when I go to change it google is saying the setting is no longer available... it is the Less Secure app access.
I will love any thoughts or direction on how to fix this problem. I am on a Mac if anyone thinks that could be causing a problem.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Mail {
    Session newSession = null;
    MimeMultipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(newSession);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException, AddressException {
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setupServerProperties();
        mail.draftEmail();
        mail.sendEmail();
    }

    private void setupServerProperties() {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //was 547 changed        // to 587
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        newSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

    }

    private MimeMessage draftEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException {


        String[] emailRecipients = {"abcd@gmail.com", "abcde@gmail.com"}; //who it is going to
        String emailSubject = "Test Mail";
        String emailBody = "Test body of email";

        for(int i =0; i< emailRecipients.length; i++ ){
            mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailRecipients[i]));
            System.out.println("This is i" + i);
        }

        MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        bodyPart.setContent(emailBody, "html/text");
        multiPart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
        mimeMessage.setContent(multiPart);
        return mimeMessage;
    }

    private void sendEmail() throws MessagingException{
        String fromUser = "yourPersonalEmail@gmail.com"; //sender
        String fromUserPassword = "yourPassword"; //Password for senders email
        String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        Transport transport = newSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserPassword);
        transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("Email Successfully sent");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use port 587 instead of 547?

Comment: Does your network's firewall have the desired port open?

Comment: @rgettman how would I check that?

Comment: @KDW I am going to try 587 now. Thank you

Comment: I would generate 'application credentials' though i can't remember how i did it ;)